# How would I go about fixing this block of code?

Tags: python

The code below is supposed to output the following if you choose employee

````
Do you wish to enter data for an (E)mployee, a (S)alesperson, or would you like to (Q)uit?: e
Enter the name of the employee: (employee name)
Enter (employee name)  hourly pay rate: (pay rate)
Enter (employee name) hours worked: (hours worked ```

Employee data: 
Employee name: (employee name)
Employee hourly pay: (hourly pay)
Hours worked: (hours worked)
Pay: (pay)
````

That is if you choose the to enter data for an employee ^^^

Here is the following output if you would like the choose the following data for a Salesperson

```
Do you wish to enter data for an (E)mployee, a (S)alesperson, or would you like to (Q)uit?: s
Enter the name of the employee: (employee name)
Enter (employee name) hourly pay rate: (hourly pay)
Enter the number of hours worked by (employee name): (hours worked)
Enter the amount of sales made by (employee name): (sales made)
Enter the commission percentage that will be earned by (employee name): (commission percentage)

Salesperson data:
Employee name: (employee name)
Employee hourly pay: (hourly pay)
Hours worked: (hours worked)
Sales: (sales made)
Commission percentage: (commission percent)
Pay: (pay)
```

Here is the entire block of code that is executing all of this. Keep in mind that this has to be done using classes and polymorphism.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, hours_worked, hourly_rate):
        self.__hours_worked = 0
        self.__hourly_rate = 0

    def set_hours_worked(self, hours_worked):
        self.__hours_worked = hours_worked

    def get_hours_worked(self):
        return self.__hours_worked

    def set_hourly_rate(self, hourly_rate):
        self.__hourly_rate = hourly_rate

    def get_hourly_rate(self):
        return self.__hourly_rate

    def calc_pay(self):
        return self.__hourly_rate * self.__hours_worked

    def __str_(self):
        print()
        string1 = 'Employee data: ' + '\n' + 'Employee name: ' + employee_name + '\n' + 'Employee hourly pay rate: ' + employee_pay + '\n' + 'Hours worked: ' + employee_hours + '\n' + 'Pay: ' + employee_pay


class Salesman(Employee):

    def __init__(self, weekly_sales, commission, hours_worked, hourly_rate):
        Employee.__init__(self, hours_worked, hourly_rate)
        self.__weekly_sales = 0
        self.__commission = 0

    def set_weekly_sales(self, weekly_sales):
        self.__weekly_sales = weekly_sales

    def get_weekly_sales(self):
        return self.__weekly_sales

    def set_commission(self, commission):
        self.__commission = commission

    def get_commission(self):
        return self.__commission

    def calc_pay(self):
        return Employee.calc_pay(self) + (self.__weekly_sales * self.__commission)

    def __str__(self):
        print()
        string2 = 'Salesperson data: ' + '\n' + 'Employee name: ' + salesperson_name + '\n' + 'Employee hourly pay rate: ' + str(
            salesperson_pay) + '\n' + 'Hours worked: ' + salesperson_hours + '\n' + 'Sales: ' + salesperson_sales + '\n' + 'Commission percentage: ' + str(
            salesperson_commission) + '\n' + 'Pay: ' + str(salesperson_pay)


go_on = 'y'

while go_on == 'y':
    input1 = input('Do you wish to enter data for an (E)mployee, a (S)alesperson, or would you like to (Q)uit?: ')
    if input1 == 'e' or 'E':
        employee_name = input('Enter the name of the employee: ')
        employee_pay = input('Enter ' + employee_name + ' hourly pay rate: ')
        employee_hours = input('Enter the number of hours worked by ' + employee_name + ': ')
        employee_pay_rate = employee_pay * int(employee_hours)
        employee = Employee(employee_name, employee_pay, employee_hours, employee_pay_rate)
        print(employee)
    if input1 == 's' or 'S':
        salesperson_name = input('Enter the name of the employee: ')
        salesperson_pay = float(input('Enter ' + salesperson_name + ' hourly pay rate: '))
        salesperson_hours = input('Enter the number of hours worked by ' + salesperson_name + ': ')
        salesperson_sales = input('Enter the amount of sales made by ' + salesperson_name + ': ')
        salesperson_commission = float(input('Enter the commission percentage that will be earned by ' + salesperson_name + ': '))
        salesperson = Salesman(salesperson_pay, salesperson_hours, salesperson_sales, salesperson_commission)
        print(salesperson)
    else:
        go_on = 'n'
```

I am sure I got mostly everything right but I'm running into a couple problems and I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: What is it that, you are facing a problem with?

Comment: My __init__() function takes 3 arguments, but it was given 5 @onlinejudge95

Comment: As far as your `Employee` class goes it does take 3 arguments, can you please post the traceback

Comment: `line 70, in <module>
    employee = Employee(employee_name, employee_pay, employee_hours, employee_pay_rate)
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given` @onlinejudge95

Comment: @KeghanPettit that's because you are passing 5 arguments in the `while` loop to `Employee` with `self` included

Comment: you got your answer, gg @spiritsree

Comment: @spiritsree I get this error when I try entering data for a salesman                    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/EET_Notes/Chapter11-2.py", line 80, in <module>
    salesperson = Salesman(salesperson_pay, salesperson_hours, salesperson_sales, salesperson_commission)
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/EET_Notes/Chapter11-2.py", line 37, in __init__
    Employee.__init__(self, hours_worked, hourly_rate, employee_name, employee_payrate)
NameError: name 'employee_name' is not defined`

Comment: @Avenius you are not accepting `employee_name` in `class Salesman(Employee):

    def __init__(self, weekly_sales, commission, hours_worked, hourly_rate):`

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** you are passing 5 arguments in the while loop to Employee with `self` included.

1. When taking input as a string from the user, use `raw_input` instead
   of `input`.
2. `input1 == "e" or "E"` is always `true`. Do `input1 == "e" or input1 == "E"`

   This way you are making use of the while loop to add as many users as needed.

And also some additional points:

- You have a base class `Employee` whose constructor or `init` accepts `(self, hours_worked, hourly_rate)`

recommended:  `(self, name, hours_worked, hourly_rate)`

- In class `Salesman`'s `__init__` method, try to maintain the order of arguments passed where the parent class `Employees` arguments come first.

recommended: `class Salesman(Employee):

```
def __init__(self, name, hours_worked, hourly rate, weekly_sales, commission):
    Employee.__init__(self, name, hours_worked, hourly_rate)
    self.__weekly_sales = 0
    self.__commission = 0`
```

Comment: Thanks for that but that is not what is needed for this lab. If this was an actual project I was working on outside of class I would do that but it is not needed at all. Right now I enter in data for a employee and I get this message, its not an error, but this is what it says "<_main__.Employee object at 0x32665D0> how would I fix this so that the __str__ command prints what the output should be instead of that? I also get an error message when I try entering data in for a salesperson because employee_name is not defined @spiritsree

Comment: do `def __str__(self):` instaead of `def __str_(self):`